# Handling GDPR Subject Access Request for Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

If we get a subject access request and we are using Google Analytics does GA have a feature where we can look up the users profile and generate all the data that GA collected for them?

Just trying to get in front of this in case we ever get any requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Analytics do *not* anonymize the data you collect on its behalf *unless* you configure it to do [IP-anonymization](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ip-anonymization).

If you use Google Analytics and *do* not use this feature, you need to have a DPA in place with Google in order to comply with the GDPR.

This is a real hassle, so unless you absolutely need fine-grained demographic data, it is strongly recommended that you use IP-anaonymization.

Comment: Just cross linking the answer from law: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/29160/handling-a-gdpr-subject-access-request-when-using-google-analytics/29262#29262

Comment: Free Radical is correct regarding IP-anonymization in that Google has the IP address on their end if IP-anonymization is disabled, however Google does not provide a way for you to access the IP of a single user or session.

Comment: @BrianNorman "however Google does not provide a way for you to access the IP of a single user or session." Google has access to this data, and to comply with the GDPR, Goggle, acting as *your processor*, *must* provide a way for you to comply with the right to access. A DPA would contractually oblige Google to give you access this personal data (this is why it is a hassle to create such a DPA).

Comment: @FreeRadical thanks for the clarification.  Seems like I find something new every day to worry about when it comes to GDPR.

Answer (score 2):

Google Analytics anonymizes and aggregates all user data so it is not possible to look up an individual user in GA unless you are sending a pseudonymous identifier such as a customer ID to cross-reference, at which point you would need prior opt-in consent from the user to remain GDPR compliant.

Comment: Perhaps this is a question for law.stackexchange but isn't the Subject Access Request effectively the prior opt in consent.  My understanding per this is that it is: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/29160/handling-a-gdpr-subject-access-request-when-using-google-analytics

Comment: Follow up question on law: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/29257/does-data-that-is-anonymized-need-to-be-collect-in-the-event-of-a-gdpr-subject-a

Comment: That is a great question and is over my head.  I'll be sure to keep an eye on your law.stackexchange question as I'm curious myself.